# Use @AuthenticationPrincipal with JwtAuthenticationToken to use own user class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.5 with Spring Security 5.2.2 using `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` and `spring-security-oauth2-jose` dependencies.

In my controller methods, I have this working:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@AuthenticationPrincipal JwtAuthenticationToken principal) {
    User user = getUser(principal);
    ...
}
```

The `principal` gets injected and contains the id of the user on Azure (I am using Azure AD B2C).

The first thing I need to do in every method is get my own `User` object using this private method that retrieves the `User` from my `userService` Spring bean:

```
    private User getUser(JwtAuthenticationToken principal) {
        AuthorizationServerUserId authorizationServerUserId = AuthorizationServerUserId.fromPrincipal(principal);
        return userService.findByAuthorizationServerUserId(authorizationServerUserId)
                          .orElseThrow(() -> UserNotFoundException.forAuthorizationServerUserId(authorizationServerUserId));
    }
```

How can I configure Spring (Boot) so that this works:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

}
```

The security configuration is currently done like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .authorizeRequests(registry -> {
                    registry.antMatchers("/registration/**").permitAll();

                    registry.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what `AuthorizationServerUserId` is?

Comment: @Stuck This is a value object that keeps track of the id of the user on the authorization server. It basically encapsulates the `String` that is the "primary key" of the user on the authorization server.

Comment: ok thanks, so for future readers: think of it as `userService.findById(principal.getName())` - `principle.getName()` returns the jwt's `sub` (subject = the auth server's user id) by default.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@AuthenticationPrincipal` accepts a SpEL expression as a parameter.

You can specify the bean and method that transforms the principal into a `User` in the provided SpEL expression.

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "@userService.getUser(#this)") User user) {

}
```

where `userService` refers to the `UserService` bean.

You can take it one step further by creating a custom annotation that uses `@AuthenticationPrincipal` as a meta annotation.

```java
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "@userService.getUser(#this)")
public @interface CurrentUser {}
```

Then your controller would become

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@CurrentUser User user) {

}
```

Comment: Super answer, thanks! One thing I needed to do in my tests is instead of using `@MockBean` with a `UserService` field in my test itself, I needed to create a bean myself in the `@TestConfiguration` that I use like `@Bean public UserService userService() {return mock(UserService.class);}`. If you don't do this, there is an exception that the `userService` bean cannot be resolved.

Comment: Also: because I was using `Optional` and a static helper method, the full expression I ended up with is `@userService.findByAuthorizationServerUserId(T(com.company.project.backend.user.authserver.AuthorizationServerUserId).fromPrincipal(#this)).orElse(null)` (Notice the `T` to be able to call a static method)

Comment: Why would you need @Targe({ElementType.TYPE}) for this one?

Comment: how do you write tests for this actually?

Answer (score 1):

You can even get any information from the token (including custom claims).

For example, we add `userId` to the token, then to get it:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "getClaims().get('userId')")
public @interface UserAuthenticationId {
}
```

And controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/me")
  public User getCurrentUser(@UserAuthenticationId String userId) {
    log.info("Get current user: {}", userId);
```

Comment: how do you write tests for this actually?