# Spring security - transform cognito JWT to custom user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement cognito authentication in spring boot. I installed oauth2-resource-server, and I see that the JWT token sent in the header is indeed verified correctly and the claims in the JWT is passed to the api endpoint.

this is my code:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String index(Principal principal) {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!" + principal.getName();
}
```

Principal indeed contains the user id from cognito. But I would like to have the user object from my database passed to the handler. Something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String index(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot!" + principal.getName();
}
```

I can't find how to do it....

Comment: By default the principal will be an instance of `Jwt`. You could use `@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt`. In your application, what is the relationship between the custom `User` object and `Jwt`? What are you trying to achieve by using `User` instead of `Jwt`?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I would like to fetch the user record from DB according to jwt user id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727265/use-authenticationprincipal-with-jwtauthenticationtoken-to-use-own-user-class/60727858#60727858